# Hide UIView on device rotation - doesn't work when device is horizontal

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uideviceorientation

I'm trying to hide an image in a view controller when the device is rotated.  I'm posting a notification in PlayerViewController and am listening for it in the app delegate, which is responsible for the bannerView:

```
- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {     

  UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

if ((orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) ||
    (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)) {

    bannerView.hidden = ([[self.navigationController visibleViewController] isKindOfClass:[PlayerViewController class]]) ? YES : NO;

} else {
    bannerView.hidden = NO;
}
}
```

The PlayerViewController sends a notification and the app delegate hides the bannerView.  However, when the device is laid flat on a table, the image shows.  Works fine when the device is held vertically but horizontally the image appears... odd.

Here is the code to send the notification:

```
 - (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
                                     duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
 ... hide other stuff in this view controller
 }
```

Any ideas why this odd behavior is occurring?

Just one tidbit more information. In the simulator the image shows when the device is in upside-down orientation, even though I have:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
 {
if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) {
    return YES;
} else {
    return NO;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error might be happening because of when you're posting the notification.

`willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` is called *before* the orientation change takes place (hence the "will" in the method name). So if we're going from portrait to landscape, the *current* orientation may still be reported as portrait (it may not, it depends).

Now, the `willAnimate...` call returns the `toInterfaceOrientation` - the orientation that is *going* to happen.

You trigger your notification when you receive the `willAnimate`... call, and inside that notification call `[[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation]`: **which will return portrait**. Instead of requesting the orientation in your notification method you should instead pass the orientation provided in the `willAnimate` call.

If that wasn't clear, the one sentence summary: `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` is called **before the rotation changes**.

Comment: Looks like I jumped the gun.  The dang thing is still showing even though I moved the notification to willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:

Comment: Ah, sorry about that - perhaps this will work: UIDevice returns the orientation of the device itself, not necessarily your UI, so there is also a `UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp` and `FaceDown` value. Try throwing a breakpoint into your method, it might be that's being returned and is messing up your conditional.

Comment: Been through the same pain as you many months ago, back when the iPad came out - people kept putting the thing down on tables, same problem! Glad I could help

Comment: Hmmm... one more thing.  Now the image shows when the device is at a 45 degree angle... not 50 degrees, not 30 degrees, but 45.  What is causing this?